# Cognito: is it possible to host UI on my domain and redirect to my domain too?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to use Cognito for my WebExtension for Chromium and Firefox.

I have two problems.

1) Hosted UI from Cognito not at my domain - so users may think why:

[image: Cognito hosted UI]

For branding and security I want to host UI from Cognito on my domain. Because my product is the browser extension - I think that I can embed UI for login in iframe to the popup-ui (that shows if user push to the button of the extension).

2) Redirect after Google to the AWS - because of that user will see `Choose an account to continue to amazoncognito.com` but the correct text must be `Choose an account to continue to <domain-of-my-project>`:

[image: Google signing oath2]

Looks like this is not possible to redirect to my domain with saving automation of Cognito about exchanging of `code` from Google to `access token` from Google for getting email of user. In the [documentation about domain for user pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-assign-domain.html?shortFooter=false) mentioned only sub-sub-sub domain under `amazoncognito.com`. If this is not possible - would be useful to mention it in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add customized domain is not available now. We have heard this request from multiple customers and would look into adding it into our future releases.
I'm confused about your second question, can you explain more about it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My second question is about text `Choose an account to continue to amazoncognito.com` while for users will be more understandable if they can see `Choose an account to continue to <my-domain>`. Google automatically set this domain link according to the return url.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your 2nd question. It's true that ideally you would want to be able to have a custom domain, but the fact google is showing `amazoncognito.com` is a problem with your configuration in your GCP account.

Under the API->Credentials tab in GCP console, you can adjust the product name and logo to be displayed. The problem is that you need to pass a review of your app before google starts showing them. This was changed by google after some phishing hacking attempts (https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html).

To submit your app for a review: https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Comment: After my submission for a review I received the email with such text: `Scope names provided by you  do not need approval and thus inapplicable for the verification process`, my scopes: `profile email openid`.